# Dual Boot System: Two EFI partitions in two separate disks - want to wipe one disk

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, partitioning, multi-boot, boot-partition

I am using a Windows 10/Ubuntu 18.04 dual boot system, and the Windows OS is stored in my 500 GB SSD (Disk C:), and the Ubuntu OS is stored in my 3TB HDD (Disk D:). I was doing some experiments with the Ubuntu OS, and I broke my Ubuntu system, so I am planning on clearing my HDD and reinstalling the Ubuntu OS.

I was ran diskmgmt.msc and found that I had two EFI partitions, one in each disk (one in the SSD, one in the HDD; [photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIQsU.png)). I am guessing that the EFI partition in the SSD (Disk C:) is for my Windows system and the EFI partition in the HDD (Disk D:) is for my Ubuntu system... but I am afraid to wipe my D: disk because I am not completely sure if it is the EFI partition for my Ubuntu system or my Windows system; I do not want to mess my Windows system up, because it has some important projects I have been working on.

**Is there a way to find which EFI partition is for which OS, so that I can safely wipe my D: disk without breaking anything in my Windows system?** Thanks a ton!

Comment: Probably there's only one for both, as usual. The ESP being used is determined by the drives boot order.

Comment: Moved [to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128021/discussion-between-user1686-and-changanauto).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boot from a Linux live USB (making sure to boot in UEFI mode). Run `efibootmgr -v` and find the "Windows Boot Manager" boot entry. Should look like this (example is line-wrapped for clarity):

```
# efibootmgr -v
Boot000D* Windows Boot Manager
    HD(2,GPT,9c2d4ffe-c42a-4d89-bdaf-1c77bee95cae,0x96800,0x32000)
    /File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi)
    WINDOWS.........
```

The GUID in `HD(2,GPT,...)` is a partition GUID that corresponds to the "PARTUUID" in `lsblk`:

```
# lsblk -o name,size,partuuid
NAME      SIZE PARTUUID
sda     931.5G
├─sda1    512M 9c2d4ffe-c42a-4d89-bdaf-1c77bee95cae
└─sda2  923.1G 22b80d95-d702-4d75-a8d4-dc8b7182bc56
```

If you find a matching partition – that's the one which must be kept. (Conveniently, in your case, the two have completely different sizes so they should be easy to recognize.)

You can also `mount` each partition and inspect its contents. If the partition contains an `EFI/Microsoft/Boot` directory with a `bootmgfw.efi` file, that's Windows. If it *doesn't* contain such a file, it definitely is not used by Windows.

Now that you know which partition is the Windows one, you can use `fdisk` or `gdisk` or `cfdisk` to delete partitions from the *other* disk.

Comment: Yes, although pretty much any UEFI-compatible bootable Linux USB should work, not necessarily Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Since the two EFI partitions are not of the same size, here is a simple
way to find the one you are booting from:

- Run the Command Prompt (CMD) as Administrator
- Enter the command: `mountvol f: /s` (you may choose another letter for `f:`)
- Enter the command: `dir f:`
- The size on `f:` of the free space will tell which disk is this.
  If more than 99 MB then this is the larger one.
- To undo the mount, enter the command: `mountvol f: /d`.

Here is the result on my computer:

[image]